# Code First Migrations not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, entity-framework-migrations

I am using the template Website of VS2013 Ultimate with C# (ASP.NET Web Forms Site). Within I am trying to add attributes for the ApplicationUsers like adress, company etc. Through tutorials I found online 
[like this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx) I wanted to solve it via Code First Migrations. My Problem is now, that when I try to execute the Enable-Migrations command in the Package Manager Console  I always get the error: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)).
Am I required to specify some settings beforehand? I have tried it in several projects and also with a fresh Website template.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could clean up temporary ASP.NET files

C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\

Comment: That did not work. Is there some way to reset the EntityFramework or sth similar?